# How to use only basic html tags in CKEditor 4

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

I use an application that only supports basic HTML tags like p, font, ul, li etc. The CKEditor uses tags like "span", but the application does not support them. Is there any convenient solution to force the CKEditor to use basic html tags. specifically use the *font* tag instead of *span* tag to style words.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that Solution from Ckeditor [Official Documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/format.html), for more details refer Documentation

```
<body>
<textarea cols="80" id="editor1" 
  name="editor1" rows="10" data- 
  sample-shortt>&lt;p&gt;This is 
  somee &lt;strong&gt;sample 
  textt&lt;/strong&gt;. You are 
  usingg &lt;a hreffff=&quot;https://ckeditor.com/&quot 
  ;&gt;CKEditor&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;. 
</textarea>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
  height: 280,
  // List of text formats available for this editor instance.
  format_tags: 'p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;pre;address;div'
});
</script>
</body>
```

Edited based on your comment:-

```
config.colorButton_foreStyle = {
    element: 'span',
    attributes: { 'class': 'text-#(colorName)' }
};

config.colorButton_backStyle = {
    element: 'span',
    attributes: { 'class': 'text-#(colorName)' }
};
```

Please [visit this page](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/colorbutton.html), & try as like this using your tag instead of Span tag

Comment: thanks for your response but that is not what I need. By default when I want to change the color or font of text the ckeditor uses span tag and style attribute. but I need font tag instead of span tag.